# problem : find the coefficients of linear system used to build a digital oscillator ..?

Tags: oscillator, control, control-system, transfer-function

[image]

Please can one explain to me

I having difficulty on how to start

Thank you all

*** can anyone correct me if anything is wrong ! [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a 3rd order TF, stability is easily determined from the relative values of the denominator coefficients.

For the denominator, \$ds^3+as^2+bs+c\$, if:

\$ab>cd\$ the TF is stable,

\$ab=cd\$ the TF is marginally stable (i.e. a sine wave),

\$ab<cd\$ the TF is unstable.

Comment: Can I use Routh–Hurwitz  matrix to find the values of a and b and c the make the system marginally stable... ?

Comment: b=c/a ( after routh–Hurwitz test) which is the same as yours for marginally stable .

Comment: But now you to relate this to answer the question he asked for w to be equal 1 !

Comment: If the TF is marginally stable (steady-state sine wave), the denominator must factorise to: \$(s+\alpha)(s^2+\omega ^2)\$. Let \$\omega=1\$, hence find \$\alpha\$. Note that \$d=1\$ in the original TF

Comment: s^3+alpha(s^2)+s+alpha=0 according to routh test b=c/a=1 so assume any valus for alpha it will satisfy b=c/a right !

Comment: Yes, any value for \$\alpha\$ will do it. The answer gives a ROT which is easier to apply than going through Routh for a 3rd order TF.

Comment: I have another question on nyquist criteria if want to check it and help me with it  :)

Comment: Post it as a question, I'm sure someone will help if I can't.

Comment: It is already posted :)